# Seaborn tsplot not showing CI bands

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, confidence-interval, seaborn

I have a sample dataframe [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/d9ublo17h8lundl/test.pickle?dl=0) (it's the pickle for the `df`).  When I do the following:

```
df = pd.read_pickle('test.pickle')
sns.tsplot(data=df.sort('time', ascending=True), time='time', unit='entity', condition='prior_type', value='perf')
```

I get the following output (nothing):
[image]

When I change it to use `unit_traces` I can actually see the data

```
sns.tsplot(data=df.sort('time', ascending=True), time='time', unit='entity', condition='prior_type', value='perf', err_style='unit_traces')
```

[image]

My question is why can't I see the CI's?  The data is a bit disjoint in some places but I would still think it should be able to come up with some sort of confidence band.  Am I missing something here?

Comment: Your axes differ by almost four orders of magnitude... Is the scaling breaking somehow and you just need to rescale the first plot to 0-400?

Comment: @AN6U5 I tried, I actually meant to re-scale the first plot, there are some very large outliers in my data but the vast majority are on the scale of the second plot, so I would expect to see some confidence intervals around there

Comment: This looks like what happens when the y-axis limits are set to `None`, maybe try setting the `ylim` through `pyplot` e.g. `plt.ylim((0, 400))`, although I'm not sure why the limits don't get set in the first place.

Comment: By the way, the pickle documentation (https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) advises "Never unpickle data received from an untrusted or unauthenticated source." So in the future, it's better to just provide a few rows of your dataframe.

Comment: @exp1orer Noted, I mainly did it to ensure sufficient data for the plot, but will take that into consideration for the future, thanks for the note

Comment: Does your dataframe have missing values? If so you'll need to use a nan-safe estimator like `scipy.stats.nanmean`.

Comment: Also, @sedavidw , often when trying to create a minimal example that reproduces the problem, you'll solve it yourself! Happens to me all the time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The default estimator (`numpy.mean`) produces NaNs if there are missing data, which matplotlib simply avoids plotting (often helpful, but here possibly confusing). Using a nan-safe estimator, such as `scipy.stats.nanmean` should work. Sorry that this is not more obvious in the documentation.

Answer (score 6):

`scipy.stats.nanmean` is deprecated as of scipy 0.15.0 in favour of `numpy.nanmean`. Read more in [scipy 0.15.0 documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.nanmean.html).